# Custom prompt using Net::Appliance::Session

Tags: cisco, perl

I am trying to ssh into a Cisco switch using the Perl module [Net::Appliance::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Appliance::Session) but I am running into an issue due to the nature of the expected prompt.  The switch prompt is the following

> User Name:

so when the basic username prompt is expected it is not returned properly.  Looking at the documentation for [Net::Appliance::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Appliance::Session) it talks about custom prompts but I am unsure how to implement it.  It refers to Phrasebook.

If any one has any examples of how this may be achieved, it would be greatly appreciated.

To avoid cross posting I had asked a similar question at perlmonks yesterday, here's the link to that thread  http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1199230

Thanks in advance.

Code example ---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::Appliance::Session;

my $host = '<my_host>';
my $user = '<my_user>';
my $pass = '<my_password>';

my $session = Net::Appliance::Session->new( personality => 'cisco', host => $host, transport => 'SSH', );
$session->connect( username => $user, password => $pass ) or die "Cannot Connect! : $!";

my @output = $session->cmd('show version');

$session->close;

print join("\n",@output);
```

### UPDATE

I've changed my code to use a custom Phrasebook as described  [Net::CLI::Interact::Phrasebook](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eoliver/Net-CLI-Interact-2.200009/lib/Net/CLI/Interact/Phrasebook.pm)

My phrase book file looks like :

```
prompt user
    match /[Uu]ser\s*[Nn]ame:\s*?$/

prompt pass
    match /[Pp]assword: ?$/

prompt prompt
    match / ?$/

prompt basic
    match /> ?$/

macro paging
    send terminal length %s
```

And my updated script looks like :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::Appliance::Session;

my $host = '<my_host>';
my $user = '<my_user>';
my $pass = '<my_password>';

my $session = Net::Appliance::Session->new({
    add_library     => '/home/edunn/switch',
    personality     => 'custom',
    transport       => 'SSH',
    host            => $host,
    connect_options => { opts => [ '-q', ], },
});

$session->set_global_log_at('debug');

$session->connect($user,$pass ) or die "Cannot Connect! : $!";

my @output = $session->cmd('show version');

$session->close;

print join("\n",@output);
```

But now I get the following error

```
   [0.001516] p  finding prompt
   [0.006937] t  creating Net::Telnet wrapper for ssh
   [0.007171] t    command expands to:  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -q -l cisco 192.168.2.17
   [1.325789] d    SEEN:


   [1.341702] p   reading phrasebook /home/edunn/switch/custom/login
   [1.342318] p    storing prompt user
   [1.343439] p    storing prompt pass
   [1.344178] p    storing prompt prompt
   [1.344881] p    storing prompt basic
   [1.345578] p    storing macro paging
   [1.346353] p    nope, doesn't (yet) match basic
   [1.346577] p    nope, doesn't (yet) match pass
   [1.346789] p    nope, doesn't (yet) match user
   [1.347021] p   hit, matches prompt prompt
   [1.347718] p   prompt has been set to (?-xism: ?$)
   [1.348436] e  running macro paging
   [1.348655] e   macro params are: 0
   [1.349293] e  executing actions
   [1.349814] e    dispatching to execute method
   [1.350736] t   callback received for send
   [1.350957] t    queueing data for send: "terminal length 0"
   [1.351277] t   callback received for match
   [1.351576] d    SEEN:

   [1.351772] t    output matched (?-xism: ?$), storing and returning
   [1.352222] p   setting new prompt to (?-xism: ?$)
   [1.352437] p   prompt has been set to (?-xism: ?$)
   [1.353120] e  running macro paging
   [1.353323] e   macro params are: 24
   [1.353860] e  executing actions
   [1.354344] e    dispatching to execute method
   [1.355083] t   callback received for send
   [1.355290] t    queueing data for send: "terminal length 24"
   [1.355535] t   callback received for match
   [1.438431] d    SEEN:
t
   [1.438731] t    output matched (?-xism: ?$), storing and returning
   [1.439212] p   setting new prompt to (?-xism: ?$)
   [1.439426] p   prompt has been set to (?-xism: ?$)
```

Looking at the error it looks like it is matching User Name: and Password: but then it fails looking for something called prompt which I have no idea where it is picking it up from.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### answer to update

From the [Phrasebook docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::CLI::Interact::Manual::Phrasebook) I see

> The last essential prompt is of course a simple command line prompt match, and this should be named generic.
>
> ```
> # example only!
> prompt generic
>     match /> ?$/
> ```

Adding that should take care of your current issue.

I looked for how they handle inheritance so you could get all of the existing stuff like the basic prompt for free.  My best guess is that it is based on the directory structure.  If you place you `custom` directory with its `pb` in a directory below `cisco` with its `pb` or a copy of it that might work.

### original answer

It looks like from the [Phrasebook docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::CLI::Interact::Manual::Phrasebook) that `personality => 'cisco'` is sort of generic.  You might have better luck with `IOS` or one of the other variants.  I'm not that familiar with Cisco's lineage so you should look for what makes the most sense to you.

But upon further examination that may not help much.  From [the source](https://metacpan.org/source/OLIVER/Net-CLI-Interact-2.200009/lib/Net/CLI/Interact/phrasebook/cisco/pb) it looks like it is looking for `Username` or `username`, but not `User Name`.  Can you change the prompt to conform to one of the ones it is looking for?

Comment: I am trying to create a custom prompt as described in the Phrasebook docs but now get a different error.  I will post my changed above

Comment: updated the code one more time.  I no longer get an error but I also don't get any output from the issued command.

Comment: You should change `prompt basic` or `prompt prompt` into `prompt generic` depending on which one is the normal prompt.    Reread the part of the docs I quoted.

Comment: if I replace prompt prompt with prompt generic it errors out, it is still looking for prompt prompt

Comment: Have you tried starting with one of the existing profiles?

Comment: I ended solving this problem by upgrading my switch firmware.  The updated firmware allows me user authentication via ssh so I no longer need to rely on the prompts to login.  Thank you for all your help.